# How to smoothly go from one location to another when changing coordinates in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script

I set up a select field where people can switch to different continents view on google maps depending on which option they select

```
$('#location-filters').on('change', function() {

if( $(this).val() == "World" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat: 12.755724,
    lng: -3.492369
  });
  map.setZoom(2);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Europe" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : 58.1293954,
    lng : 11.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "North-america" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : 45.1293954,
    lng : -81.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "South-america" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : -20.1293954,
    lng : -60.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Middle-east" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : 34.1293954,
    lng : 38.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(6);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Africa" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : 0.1293954,
    lng : 31.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Asia" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : 40.1293954,
    lng : 90.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Oceana" ){
  map.setCenter({
    lat : -20.1293954,
    lng : 130.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}



});
```

When you change the option selected, the map center point change works but it just snaps to the new location.

How can I make it so that there's a smooth progressive effect (like a normal google maps finger drag effect) when switching between one continent and another instead of jumping directly to the new view?

I thought of changing the coordinates progressively instead of directly changing the values but I honestly have no idea how to do it so that I'm able to test it and see if it works.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I tried using `map.panTo` and it's still snapping to the new location...

```
  $('#location-filters').on('change', function() {

if( $(this).val() == "World" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat: 12.755724,
    lng: -3.492369
  });
  map.setZoom(2);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Europe" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : 58.1293954,
    lng : 11.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "North-america" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : 45.1293954,
    lng : -81.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "South-america" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : -20.1293954,
    lng : -60.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Middle-east" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : 34.1293954,
    lng : 38.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(6);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Africa" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : 0.1293954,
    lng : 31.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Asia" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : 40.1293954,
    lng : 90.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}

if( $(this).val() == "Oceana" ){
  map.panTo({
    lat : -20.1293954,
    lng : 130.556663
  });
  map.setZoom(4);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [map.panTo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panTo) but set your zoom level so that the change between both points (actual and new) is less than the width and height of the map, to get a smooth transition.

> panTo(latLng)
>
> Parameters:
>
> latLng:  LatLng|LatLngLiteral
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map.panTo`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panTo) instead of `map.setCenter`

Comment: I replaced all the map.setCenter to map.panTo and its still behaving the same way :/